# getting difficulty in passing parameter in ajax-jquery function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I want to pass value of **i** as a parameter for autosuggest.  My intention is to pass value of **i** starting from 1960 to till date.

```
         <script>

            var i=1960;
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
            //document.write("The year is " + year);
            while (i <= year)
            {
                //document.write("The year is " + i);
                //document.write("<br />");

                $("#txtYear").autocomplete([+i], {
                width: 100,
                //multiple: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                matchContains: true,
                //formatItem: formatItem,
                //formatResult: formatResult
                });
                i++;
            }
                      });
                    </script>
```

Please help me out. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is adding autocomplete to the elements 40+ times!

Anyways, jQuery autocomplete accepts an array for data. Why not build the array beforehand? [Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JJMTA/). I have to say jQuery is picky with the data. They have to be strings.

```
var i = 1960,                          //first year
    currentTime = new Date(),          
    year = currentTime.getFullYear(),  //latest year
    data = [];                         //year array

while (i <= year){                     //construct year array
    data.push(''+i++);                 //minor string conversion by concatenating
}

$("#txtYear").autocomplete({
    source: data                       //use year array
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But in my case its not working. :(

Comment: What actually I want is , when I am typing 19 , then textbox automatically should start suggesting the years. Its working in the case of month and date. my code for date is as follows :

Comment: $("#txtMonth").autocomplete(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"], {
     width: 100,
     //multiple: true,
     mustMatch: true,
     matchContains: true,
     //formatItem: formatItem,
     //formatResult: formatResult
    });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11180/discussion-between-shashi-roy-and-joseph)

Comment: Thanks... its working... There was a mistake from my side... Your code is perfect... Thanks once again...  :)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an array of the values you want, then set it in the autocomplete like this:

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: years
    });
```